# How can I get a black background while images are loading?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here is an incredibly simple application that loads a window with a Black background.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="1365" Height="768"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Background="Black">
</Window>
```

Works great, but if I add an image control, I expect it to display black for a second until my image has loaded.

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/assets/images/bg.jpg" />
```

But for some reason the background is showing white instead. The image displays perfectly fine after it loads, but I want the that 1 second of loading to be BLACK, not white.

How can I display a black background while my images are loading??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to load the image from the background, that didn't work.  I tried to load the image and use animations to animation from 0 to large, but that didn't really work and you would have to use a fixed width.  Finally, I just figured I'd change the visibility using a storyboard that's fired when the `Image.Loaded` event is fired.

In the working solution, the visibility of the Grid holding the image will go from Collapsed to Visible 0.1 seconds *after* the Image.Loaded event fires.  You can prove that this works by changing the default visibility of the "MG" `Grid` to Hidden or Visible and notice that the window is White for a longer period of time than when its sets to Collapsed.

### Working XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525"
        Background="Black">
    <Grid x:Name="MG" Background="Black" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/assets/images/bg.jpg">
            <Image.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetName="MG"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*Note:* You may have to adjust the timing depending on how big the file size is of the image you're rendering.

Comment: It's amazing how such a simple idea requires that much effort in WPF. I had considered using the event trigger on load, but it wasn't working for me because I had set visiblity to "hidden" instead of "collapsed". Thanks for providing a working example.

Comment: @Karmacon I had just finished up reading on animations, so this was an "impulse" answer.  I think you could do similar in code-behind too.

Comment: As a newcomer, I can really understand why WinForms is still so popular.