# Xaml Storyboard Animation not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to fix a UI that had an animation previously. It had a Picture that rendered on the interface when the app is loaded. I am having a tough time trying to get over the learning curve of XAML. Also if someone has  a resource where I can better learn XAML I would really appreciate it. The issues is nothing shows the image does not render on start and there is not animation as far as I can tell.

```
<Image x:Name="T_Image" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       Height="300" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       Width="300" 
       Source="Resources/Picture.png" 
       OpacityMask="Black" 
       Panel.ZIndex="1">
    <Image.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="T_Image"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                     From="300" To="85" Duration="00:00:00.75" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="T_Image"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                     From="300" To="105" Duration="00:00:0.75" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image does not get rendered at all, it is likely that the `Image.Source` URI is incorrect.  Read up on using the proper [Pack URIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and it may solve your problem.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925329/how-can-i-get-a-black-background-while-images-are-loading/33926571#33926571) is an answer I gave previously that worked just fine.  The image resource was located in the same project as the XAML and is under an `assests/images` folder.

Comment: The Image shows up when I am in the designer but when i start the application nothing renders. Also I tried what you said what was in the link and i get the same effect?

Comment: @user3753693 any reason `OpacityMask="Black" Panel.ZIndex="1"` is set? can you remove those? any chance you can reproduce in a new project?

Comment: Also, make sure you're using the correct `pack uri`.  Are you working with a single project or multiple? Is the image in the correct location? Is that location a local file or on the network?  Look in the output window to see if there are any errors/warnings when you run the application.

Comment: I tried using a static URL (C:\user\location\project\resources\image.png) and the image shows up on run time but no animation. I removed the opacity mask and panel z index, file is local, no errors or warnings in output window

Comment: Fixed it using my original and code, Deleting the OpacityMask Panel Z index and changing to a static path fixed the issue now i just have to find a way to make the path dynamic to any machine its ran on

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using my original and code, Deleting the OpacityMask Panel Z index and changing to a static path fixed the issue now i just have to find a way to make the path dynamic to any machine its ran on